# FilterConfig on Docfx isn't working and stack is asking for more letters on my tittle

Tags: docfx

Stack is asking for more detail but the info below is more than enough, if something is missing please lemme know

filterConfig.yml

```yaml
apiRules:
- exclude:
  uidRegex: ClassLibrary1
  type: Namespace
```

The project

[image]

The *docfx.json*

```json
"metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "**/*.csproj"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api",
      "filter": "filterConfig.yml"
    }
  ],
```

The page

[image]

Docfx version:
2.75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding at least one more space in the rules nested on the `exclude` filter. This is due to [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-6-structural-productions) which says:

> Each node must be indented further than its parent node. All sibling nodes must use the exact same indentation level. However the content of each sibling node may be further indented independently.